# How to Stop Inserting?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How would i will stop looping if the value is already existing?

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON    
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON    
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_Sproc_Result]     
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @employeeid bigint,
    @providercode varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM TR_employeesprovidercode    
                 WHERE employeeid = @employeeid
                  AND providercode = @providercode)
  BEGIN
      Insert into TR_employeesprovidercode 
        (employeeid, providercode) 
      values 
        (@employeeid, @providercode)
  END

END
```

C# code

s my code in C#...

```
foreach (ArrayList item in ArrData)

{

    HCSProvider.NewProviderResult oResult; oResult =
       oHCSProvider.CreateNewProvider(providercode, oProviderDetail);

    DBInterface ProviderDetail = new DBInterface();

    ProviderDetail.InsertProvider(
        Convert.ToInt64(providercode),
        Convert.ToString(oProviderDetail));

}
```

Comment: foreach (ArrayList item in ArrData)
            {   providercode = 201110001;
                oProviderDetail = "HCS";
                DBInterface ProviderDetail = new DBInterface();
                ProviderDetail.InsertProvider(Convert.ToInt64(providercode), Convert.ToString(oProviderDetail));
               
            }

Comment: Yeah. A loop got lost ;)

Comment: is it in `white font`? I dont see it in your code above?

Comment: it is my code in c#. sorry guys! i forgot. X)

Comment: @man: can you put your C# code in the original question rather than the comments? Also make sure it's formatted correctly (using the toolbar). Otherwise I suspect this question will be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NOT EXISTS first doesn't scale well and you can still get duplicate errors.

Why not try something like this?

```
...
DECLARE @rtn int
BEGIN TRY
  Insert into TR_employeesprovidercode 
    (employeeid, providercode) 
  values 
    (@employeeid, @providercode)
  SET @rtn = 0
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF ERROR_NUMBER() <> 2627
     RAISERROR ('real error', 16, 1)
  SET @rtn = 1
END CATCH
RETURN @rtn
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ELSE` part to the stored proc and return some constant.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
 BEGIN   
   ...   
 END
ELSE
 RETURN 0;
```

In your loop check for the return value and break from the loop.

```
foreach(var item in myArray)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); // command for stored proc
    ...
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if(result == 0)
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use and output parameter in your stored procedure and populate the value if the entry is a duplicate.  Then test the parameter and break the loop if the value already exists.

[Here's](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Stored_Procedures.htm) the MySql Tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to return a value from the stored procedure that you can check, and then `break` the loop on an appropriate return value.