# Stop Looping C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How to stop my Loop if the value is already existing?

here's my code in C#...

```
foreach (ArrayList item in ArrData)
{    
  HCSProvider.NewProviderResult oResult;
  oResult = oHCSProvider.CreateNewProvider(providercode, oProviderDetail)

  DBInterface ProviderDetail = new DBInterface(); 

  ProviderDetail.InsertProvider(Convert.ToInt64(providercode), Convert.ToString(oProviderDetail));
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just edit your original question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482188/how-to-stop-inserting

Comment: i think i had a problem in my C#'s code. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you can skip iteration with

```
continue;
```

and stop loop with

```
break;
```

Comment: if there is an existing values in my database or after inserting a values my loop will stop?

Answer (score 16):

If you are inside a loop and want to abort the loop execution and jump to the code after the loop, insert a `break;` statement.

If you only want to stop the current loop iteration, and continue with the rest of the loop, add a `continue;` statement instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can stop any loop in c# by a `break` statement

You can write something like this:

```
foreach(var o in list)
{
 if (o.SomeValue == 1)
 {
   break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Continue, break and goto are used in C# for skipping the loop.

**Continue**
Skips the execution of current iteration

```
Continue;
```

**break**
Comes out of the loop and continues the next statement after the loop

```
break;
```

**goto**
 is normally not recommend, but still can be used to move control out of the loop

```
goto Outer;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a break command to exit from For Loop.

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
if(item == myitem)
{
break;
}
Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily stop your lop on a condition with the **break** statement!

Small example:

```
var arr = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int temp = 0;

foreach(var item in arr)
{
    temp = item +1;
    if(temp == 5)
    {
        break;
            //...
    }
     //do something
}
```