# How do I select random records while looping through the collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, loops, for-loop

```
foreach (var n in BooksList)
            {
                for (int t=0; t< ReadersList.Count; t++)
                {
                    BooksReadersList.Add(new BooksReaders() { BookID= n.BookID, ReaderID= Readers[t].ReaderID});
                }
            }
```

now If I iterate through it it's ok, working but i want to do 2 things

1. The inner loop shall run only 3 times
2. Each time the inner shall pick a random ReaderID instead of sequential e.g. Readers has 10 records in it i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 primary records. So, among it the inner loop shall pick randomly i.e. 3,10, 7, 4, 2, 1, 4.

Comment: Randomize the list first.  Break out of the loop when you've added three items.

Comment: @LarsTech: break out of the loop? means? sorry didn't get.

Comment: See [Stop Looping C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482377/719186)

Comment: that i have done alreayd when it hits counter 3 but how to select random.

Comment: Do you want to take random 3 records from BooksList?

Comment: @CagriD.Kaynar readerslist....

Comment: var  random3= ReadersList.OrderBy(x=>Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);

Comment: ah ok so i have to loop throught the random3 now instead of the readers list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Random` to peek a random reader in list

```
Random random = new Random();
Reader reader = readerList[random.Next(0, readerList.Count - 1)];
```

Example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZVDnuF

Comment: i agree, but it is repeating the number in the same iteration, i have seen.

Comment: This code doesn't repeat readers, you are talking about books? If yes, remove the inner for